Заблокирована дорожная сеть anylogic
После очередного запуска модели вся дорожная сеть вдруг оказалась некликабельна, хотя блокировка снята.
Два раза отображалось окно с ошибкой:
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.getActivePart()" because the 
return value of "org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPartSite.getPage()" is null 

Закрытие модели и перезапуск Anylogic  ничего не дал. До перезагрузки другие модели тоже были не кликабельны, после только одна, в которой работаю.
Может кто то сталкивался и сможет подсказать?
